# LoginView Password Recovery in Razor View Engine

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, loginview

I have a website I built in MVC4 in razor view engine.  I moved the database tables that were doing the encryption from the local database to our production database and changed the web.config file to adjust for this change.  It now works fine, but I need to recover passwords.  SO I end up having hashed passwords.  Is there any way to translate it to recover the password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's the point of a hash -> one way. it's not meant to be decrypted. instead, reset the user's password and notify the user of their new password. they can always log in and change it again.

Comment: So is there a way to reset it?  Not familiar with how.  Only way I know is to delete the account and create a new account with the same name and a different password

Comment: assuming your using the Membership provider static gateway to manage user accounts use the create password and change password methods. then inform the user of the new password (on screen, email, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Not easily. Thats the point of a hash, its a one way function. You would have to crack it some how.